# mongo find documents where subdocument matches multiple criteria

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection similar to

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("57832cb74114065710110971"), 
"strName" : "Some Book In Library", 
"strUPN" : "123456", 
"bHardCover": "yes",
"bIsDamaged" : "yes", 
"arrWhoHasRead" : [
    {
        "nUserID" : ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1"), 
        "strPersonName" : "John Doe", 
        "strRole" : "Author"
    },
{
        "nUserID" : ObjectId("xyz"), 
        "strPersonName" : "Jane Doe", 
        "strRole" : "Customer"
    }
]
}
```

I want to return all records that have bIsDamaged = yes, and bHardCover = yes
AND where (arrWhoHasRead.nUserID = 577b0b8d41140640f94894a1 AND arrWhoHasRead.strRole="Author")

I tried nesting my multiple AND condition (the one in paranthesis) in an array but that didn't seem to help much. Maybe I need projection?

I'm using this in PHP

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display all record matching your requirements including all  other elements of `arrWhoHasRead`, a `find` is enough :

```
db.device.find({"bHardCover": "yes","bIsDamaged" : "yes","arrWhoHasRead.nUserID":ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1"),"arrWhoHasRead.strRole":"Author"});
```

which will give you :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("578d7f9aca19a63da3984899"),
    "strName": "Some Book In Library",
    "strUPN": "123456",
    "bHardCover": "yes",
    "bIsDamaged": "yes",
    "arrWhoHasRead": [{
        "nUserID": ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1"),
        "strPersonName": "John Doe",
        "strRole": "Author"
    }, {
        "nUserID": ObjectId("578d7d6bca19a63da3984897"),
        "strPersonName": "Jane Doe",
        "strRole": "Customer"
    }]
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("578d7fb0ca19a63da398489a"),
    "strName": "Some Book In Library",
    "strUPN": "123456",
    "bHardCover": "yes",
    "bIsDamaged": "yes",
    "arrWhoHasRead": [{
        "nUserID": ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1"),
        "strPersonName": "John Doe",
        "strRole": "Author"
    }, {
        "nUserID": ObjectId("578d7d6bca19a63da3984898"),
        "strPersonName": "Jane Doe",
        "strRole": "Customer"
    }]
}
```

If you want to have in results only the elements of `arrWhoHasRead` matching `ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1")`, you can do an `aggregate` but no need for projection unless you want to exclude some other field :

```
db.device.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$arrWhoHasRead"
}, {
    $match: {
        "bHardCover": "yes",
        "bIsDamaged": "yes",
        "arrWhoHasRead.nUserID": ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1"),
        "arrWhoHasRead.strRole": "Author"
    }
}])
```

which will give :

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("578d7f9aca19a63da3984899"),
    "strName": "Some Book In Library",
    "strUPN": "123456",
    "bHardCover": "yes",
    "bIsDamaged": "yes",
    "arrWhoHasRead": {
        "nUserID": ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1"),
        "strPersonName": "John Doe",
        "strRole": "Author"
    }
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("578d7fb0ca19a63da398489a"),
    "strName": "Some Book In Library",
    "strUPN": "123456",
    "bHardCover": "yes",
    "bIsDamaged": "yes",
    "arrWhoHasRead": {
        "nUserID": ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1"),
        "strPersonName": "John Doe",
        "strRole": "Author"
    }
}
```

Note that the array has been unwind so you will only have json object in `arrWhoHasRead` &  as much as record as there are `ObjectId("577b0b8d41140640f94894a1")` in `arrWhoHasRead`